# Laravel Eloquent order by sum with where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my tables :

```
    user
       id
       name

   battles
      user1_id
      user2_id
      vote1
      vote2

   users
       id
       name
```

I want to get the users orders by total win but i can't find how to do it with Eloquent.

Here an example (this don't work, it's just for illustrate) :

```
User:orderBy(sum('battles.vote1', '>', 'battles.vote2'),'DESC')->get();
```

But it need to also work if vote2 > vote1.

So bascilly if I have:

```
Users :
id: 1, name: John
id: 2, name: Bob
id: 3, name: Max

Battles :
user1_id : 1, user2_id : 2, vote1 : 180, vote2 : 3
user1_id : 1, user2_id : 3, vote1 : 110, vote2 : 90
user1_id : 2, user2_id : 3, vote1 : 1, vote2 : 9
user1_id : 3, user2_id : 4, vote1 : 900, vote2 : 0
user1_id : 3, user2_id : 1, vote1 : 10, vote2 : 30
```

I want to return an users collection in this order :

John (3 win, Battle 1,2,5)

Max (2 win, Battle 3,4)

Bob (0 win)

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you using a comparison inside of a sum function? Which, by the way, won't work like you think it will.

Comment: @aynber "Here an example (this don't work, it's just for illustrate) :" It's the line just under, it's for illustate what i want cause i have no idea how to do it and it's hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try sum with following request:

Getting wins by user1 side:

```
$wins1 = $this->user->battles->where('user1_id', $this->user->id)->sum('battles.vote1', '>', 'battles.vote2')->get();
```

Getting wins by user2 side:

```
    $wins2 = $this->user->battles->where('user2_id', $this->user->id)->sum('battles.vote1', '<', 'battles.vote2')->get();
```

And calculate user wins by both side:

```
 $total = $wins1 + $wins2;
```

Comment: I need a collections of all users, i know how to do it with a user:all() and foreach user one by one but it's make the page load very long